# It is possible to overcharge a AGM battery at 13.7 V?

Tags: battery-charging, lead-acid

I have an AGM lead-acid battery, TED1251, which I want to use in a UPS. I bought it new. I put it in the circuit, where it is permanently connected to 13.7 V with a current limit of 1 A. The manufacturer says that the float voltage is between 13.5 - 13.8 V.

Everything was fine, it charged up to 13.7 V, then the charging current gradually decreased to 15 mA. I left it like that and today, after about 2 weeks, a liquid came out at the negative terminal. The battery was not hot. It was at room temperature.

What do you think happened to it? Did I overcharge it? But how, if I gave it only 13.7 V?

Could it have a manufacturing defect ?

Is there really such a thing as float charging ? Did some of you let an AGM battery sit at 13.7 V for a year without anything bad happening to it?

If it leaked, should I consider it damaged?

[image]

Comment: How warm is it where this battery is being operated? Also, please be extremely careful with that liquid. Try to not get it onto your hands. If it really leaked from the battery, it contains dissolved lead ions and is quite poisonous. (Lead ingestion causes chronic illness.)

Comment: I'm no battery expert but at 15mA I doubt it's overcharged - I think float charging is common with lead-acid batteries, overcharging produces hydrogen gas, and the sealed ones have some kind of catalyst that turns the hydrogen gas back into water so that a slow overcharge is no problem.

Comment: @JonathanS. It si about 18-20 *C. I did not touch that liquid with my hand. I wiped it with a napkin and threw it away. After that it leaked a little more... But there is no crack anywhere in it...

Comment: @user253751 That's why I wonder too... The current was low, it did not get hot... It had no reason for this to happen...

Comment: Re, "...some kind of catalyst..." The rate at which the catalyst is able to recombine hydrogen with oxygen is limited, and the rate at which trickle charging generates hydrogen and oxygen is directly proportional to the trickle current. As long as you keep the current below the magic threshold (Is it temperature dependent? I don't know) then everything will be OK, but if the trickle current is too high, then the catalyst can't keep up, the battery will "vent," and its service life will be shortened.

Comment: ...Should have said, "too high _for too long._" Venting in a Valve Regulated Lead-Acid (VRLA) battery happens through a pressure-relief valve. A brief episode of over-charging will cause pressure to build up inside the battery, but if the current is stopped before the battery vents, then the catalyst will slowly do its work, eventually converting all of the H2 and O2 back to water, and none will be lost.

Comment: It is probably damaged. Or maybe someone spilled a small amount of liquid on it unbeknownst to you. If you are able try some type of capacity test. Generally, any type of damage to a battery will result in diminished capacity. The ideal thing would be to perform a capacity test using the same parameters as the manufacturer so you can compare to the advertised new capacity.

Comment: Are you sure that your voltmeter and ammeter are accurate? Seems unlikely, but good to check. I have several SLA batteries, and one or two show signs of leakage and corrosion around one of the terminals. I have had them for probably ten years now, and last I checked, they seemed OK. I have only occasionally put them on a charger. You might try cleaning the terminal and sealing it with epoxy or silicone. Maybe solder a wire to the terminal and seal the entire connection. It's probably OK, but make sure the enclosure is well vented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you operated the battery outside of its permitted float-charging range. The way the battery leaked indicates that it has been defective from the start.

According to [this handbook from Panasonic](https://www.tempelgroup.com/catalogos/energia/catalogo_panasonic_baterias_vrla.pdf) (page 14), VRLA batteries generally operate with a slight pressurization inside of their individual cells due to gas generation and recombination. The pressure in those Panasonic cells can reach up to 43.6 kPa (0.436 bar) above atmospheric pressure under normal operating conditions. The vent will not activate at this pressure yet; instead, the cell is supposed to rely on catalytic recombination of generated hydrogen and oxygen to lower its internal pressure again (turning the gases into water).

Your battery simply has a manufacturing defect in its seal around the negative terminal, which caused the normal operating pressure to force electrolyte out of the cells (without activating the safety vent).

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do to fix this and it'll keep leaking. You have to replace the battery. I've personally had good luck with the Yuasa NP7-12. It is a little more expensive, but probably for a good reason.

In general, you can float-charge VRLA batteries that are rated for "standby use" with no negative consequences. They're designed to withstand it.